# Is there a way to tell NServiceBus to not retry a message?

Tags: nservicebus

The "retry" system with NServiceBus is great.  It works fantastic in making sure small things like dead locks don't mess us up.

However, sometimes I KNOW that a message is bad.  Bad in the sense that no amount of retries is going to help.

**Is there a way to tell NServiceBus: "This message is a bad apple, move it to the error queue"?** (And have it skip the retries?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using NSB 3, you can take a look at the IManageMessageFailures interface.  This will allow you to plug in your functionality, but this is after the message has failed.  If you would like to get at the message earlier, then take a look at the [Message Mutators](http://docs.particular.net/samples/messagemutators/) feature.  This gets you in both at the transport layer and at the application layer.

Comment: Alas the upgrade to v3 is a bit to involved for me to do right now.

Comment: No problem, then I would take a look at using a Message Module.  This would allow you to get your hands on the message prior to processing to kick it out.

Answer (score 1):

Would calling `Bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers();` inside the handler not be a simpler way of doing this?